# Visual Studio 2017 SmartDeviceException DEP6200 error

Tags: c#, uwp, msdeploy, hyper-v, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue where Visual Studio 2015 could see my device yesterday and today after upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 I can see my device but Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 won't see it.

As said, I can see the windows phone in explorer and associated folders but can not deploy to the device.

It's unlocked.
I run Build/Deploy Solution
But then get the DEP6200 Bootstrapping failed error.

I am using Windows 10 Home on my Retina Mac with Parallels 11 but as said can see the phone in explorer just fine.

[image]

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

It looks like it is an issue with Parallels 11  based on the information I have so far.  I say that and if I find more information that points to another solution I will update this question/answer.

SO it appears to be an issue where I can no longer test on a device with Visual Studio 2017.

Strange that 2 days ago I did with Visual Studio 2015 and the only change is I installed Visual Studio 2017.
I believe the issue is to do with the Hyper V settings but do not  have more information than that.

So I installed Visual Studio 2017 on a dedicated Windows 10 computer and it deployed just fine to the windows phone 640.  Pitty as I used to be able to develop for IOS, Android and Windows all  on the same Mac.

Want to fix the issue so keen if someone has any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I had similiar problems, but without VM, so I'm not sure if it helps.

My resolution was to go into Device Manager, activate *"Show hidden Devices"*, delete all Devices under *USB devices* related to Windows Devices such as *WinUsb, Lumia*  and so on. Then turn off *Developer Mode* on the phone, turn it back on and make sure that *Device Discovery* is turned on (same Page just under the Developer Mode RadioButton). Plug it in again and start VS.

Comment: Native Windows machine was fine so your issue may have had a different cause.  My issue still present so I suspect it is still a bug with Parallels and Windows.  Appreciate the suggestion though as I did do the USB deletion idea and it did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try this way:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Turn off developer mode on phone.
3. Open Visual Studio and try to deploy. It should show error, because your phone isn't allowed to sideload apps.
4. Turn on developer mode on phone.
5. Try deploying again and now should work!

This solution is from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ada6e82-88f8-42c5-9f58-5ae6c4dd74a4/uwp-dep6200-bootstrapping-device-failed-device-cannot-be-found?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: Great suggestion and thanks for the info.  Did that but in this instance it did not help.  It does not get the opportunity to error due to sideloading not turned on.  The error is before that happens where VS2017 does not even acknowledge their is a phone connected, even though Windows 10 can see it just fine.

Comment: does work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898207/error-dep6200-bootstrapping-failed-device-cannot-be-found-smartdeviceexceptio