# Error DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no device was detected

Tags: deployment, xamarin.uwp

I have seen few posts here about same error but none worked for me.

I am trying to deploy UWP from VS2017 from one machine to a Surface machine that is USB connected to the machine running VS2017.

Both machines are running Windows 10 Pro, 17134 (1803) April Update.

Surface machine has enabled Developer Mode in "For Developers" settings and Developer Mode package is installed on it and Remote tooling for desktop is enabled. It is also USB connected to the machine running VS2017 Enterprise 15.7.5

According to MS documentation, that is all what is needed to deploy to device.  However, deploy fails with error

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no device was detected. Make sure a device is connected and powered on.  [0x80131500]   MyApp.App.UWP**

Comment: Can you use visual studio remote [debug tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017) instead of connect the two PC together?

Comment: For that, the 2 machines must be on same LAN which is not the case here.  I am trying to deploy just for testing purposes to my other machine.  Since all this failed, I created app packages and copied them to a flash drive and deployed that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to deploy either to device or to use remote debugging.

Deploying to device was failing with the same error message as above.  Interestingly, even if device (Surface in this case) is not USB connected to my dev machine at all, I get same error which basically makes sense.  But I dont know why I get that same error when I connect Surface tablet to my dev machine.

Deploying for remote debugging did not work since my Surface tablet is not connected to same LAN as my dev machine.

So, for my testing purposes, I deployed by using USB stick

1. Right click on UWP project, choose Store, then choose Create App
   Packages ....
2. In Create App Packages window, select "I want to create packages for
   sideloading"
3. Click Create
4. Leave Local Machine as target device for validation
5. click on Launch Windows App Certification Kit button to launch it
   and go through steps until complete
6. Once package is completed, I copied entire folder onto a flash drive
   and moved the content of the folder to my Surface tablet
7. Then on Surface tablet, right click on the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1
   file and choose Run This PowerShell
8. this will start deployment and deploy the app